# Graph explorer callrecords return 0 count even there is more callrecords

Tags: graph

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "NotFound",
        "message": "Could not find the requested call record. Records about calls or online meetings that started more than 30 days ago are not available.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-04-27T13:11:12",
            "request-id": "9ac16791-769c-4ae2-ac90-3a1650de721c",
            "client-request-id": "9ac16791-769c-4ae2-ac90-3a1650de721c"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the above error it show even there is call records.i have  given all access permissions.i have passed url in postman ==https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/groupid.

Comment: Where did you get the id from?  Not sure about the groupid endpoint. I'll have to look that up